# Need to use temporary variable to make REPLACE of SUBSTRING_INDEX work

Tags: mysql, substring

We're running MySQL 5.5.47 on a number of Debian servers. On some of them, we're seeing the following strange behavior:

```
mysql> set @TKEY:='ARDARD:fae590c4.ffa2.11e5.a318.0cc47a39aeb4-1460351116';  
mysql> select replace(substring_index(substring_index(@TKEY,':',-1),'-',1), '.','-') as guid;
+--------------------------------------+
| guid                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| fae5a2.1--0cc47a 9ae47a 9aeb4a 9aeb4 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

This is supposed to extract the middle part of `@TKEY` (between the `:` and `-`) and replace all the periods with hyphens. Where are the spaces coming from? Other parts of the result seem to be jumbled up: `9aeb4` has been duplicated, `a2.1` has been shifted left.

This doesn't happen if I assign the `substring_index` to an intermediate variable.

```
mysql> set @temp = substring_index(substring_index(@TKEY,':',-1),'-',1);
mysql> select replace(@temp, '.', '-') as guid;
+--------------------------------------+
| guid                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| fae590c4-ffa2-11e5-a318-0cc47a39aeb4 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

This only happens on our production servers. I can't reproduce it on our development server or sqlfiddle. I compared all the server variables, and there are no differences that look like they should affect the behavior of string functions (there were initially some differences in character set and collation variables, but I changed the dev server to match the production server and still couldn't replicate the error.

On another production server running MySQL 5.5.41 I get a slightly different wrong result:

```
mysql> select replace(substring_index(substring_index(@TKEY,':',-1),'-',1), '.','-') as guid;
+--------------------------------------+
| guid                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
| fae590c4-ffa2-11e5-a318-0cc47a 9aeb4 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

This is correct except that there's a space in place of of the last `3`.

Can anyone explain this? Is it just a MySQL bug? I couldn't find anything at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: sqlfiddle 5.5 gives strange result too..and is also solved by using intermediate temp variable...i think you've found a major bug

Comment: So I guess this is probably a bug that was fixed in 5.6. I couldn't find it when I searched closed bugs, but this looks kind of similar: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that was fixed in MySQL 5.6.5. There's a somewhat similar bug report regarding [`LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(...))`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60166). It was closed with the comment:

> Noted in 5.6.5 changelog.
>
> The result of SUBSTRING_INDEX() could be missing characters when used
> as an argument to conversion functions such as LOWER().

I suspect the underlying cause is pointer misuse resulting in buffer overflow and undefined behavior. Hopefully I haven't corrupted any long-lived memory in the server.

Comment: nice find, the suggested fix by calling it in different order works for your example as well

Comment: Great .. upvote. Look, I like to know your idea about [the only answer which is under my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358749/how-can-i-use-aliases-on-group-by-clause#39359000). Can you please take a look at it? Just tell me is that fine? Can It be better? Or it isn't good? or etc..