# How can I use aliases on GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  SUM(score) score,
    type,
    context,
    post_id,
    e.table_code,
    comment_id,
    MIN(seen) seen,
    MAX(date_time) d_t,
    (CASE   WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
        WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
        ELSE 'in last month'
    END) as range_day
FROM `events` e
WHERE e.id IN ($ids)
GROUP BY type, post_id, e.table_code, comment_id, range_day
ORDER BY seen, MAX(date_time) desc, MAX(e.id) desc
```

It throws this error:

> `#`1056 - Can't group on 'range_day'

And if I remove `range_day` from `GROUP BY` clause, then it works as well. But I need to also group the result also based on `range_day`. How can I do that?

Comment: `range_day` is a alias for the calculated column. So, it can't be used in `group by`. Use the actual calculation instead.

Comment: Repeat your case when in group by will works

Comment: `range_day` is calculated using an aggregate function `MAX`. But you can not use aggregate functions in the group by clause.

Comment: @vkp what do you mean *"actual calculation"*? Is it `date_time` column? Well it's a unique value *(almost)* .. So that aggregate functions won't work as expected.

Comment: by calculation i mean the `case` expression

Comment: To reiterate Paul's comment, you cannot group on the result of an aggregate function, or any expression that depends on such a result.

Comment: All you can do is to wrap your query into a subquery without range_day in the GROUP BY clause. Then use your GROUP BY clause in the outer query as it is. But it doesn't seam reasonable, what you are trying to do. You should describe what you want and why.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Emm I guess I got a clue `:-)` .. I will try it, but look, feel free to write an answer under my question `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are trying to do. But you can wrap your query into a subquery without `range_day` in the GROUP BY clause. Then use your GROUP BY clause in the outer query as it is.

```
SELECT  SUM(score) score,
    type,
    context, -- WARNING! Not listed in group by clause
    post_id,
    table_code,
    comment_id,
    MIN(seen) seen,
    MAX(d_t) d_t,
    range_day
FROM (
    SELECT  SUM(score) score,
        MAX(id) as id,
        type,
        context, -- WARNING! Not listed in group by clause
        post_id,
        e.table_code,
        comment_id,
        MIN(seen) seen,
        MAX(date_time) d_t,
        (CASE   WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
            WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
            WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(date_time)) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
            ELSE 'in last month'
        END) as range_day
    FROM `events` e
    WHERE e.id IN ($ids)
    GROUP BY type, post_id, e.table_code, comment_id
) sub
GROUP BY type, post_id, table_code, comment_id, range_day
ORDER BY seen, MAX(d_t) desc, MAX(id) desc
```

However - you select `context` without aggregation wich is not listed in the GROUP BY clause. Thus you will get some "random" value from the group. In strict mode the query will fail.

Comment: You've used `range_day` on `GROUP BY` clause of both inner and outer queries.

Comment: @stack - sorry, i was sure, i'v deleted it :-) - You will probably find some other mistakes, while testing. I don't have data/schema to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `range_day` doesn't exactly make sense.  Why does it use `MAX()`?  Max of what?

A natural way to make the query work is to remove the `MAX()` from the definition:

```
SELECT SUM(score) score, type, context, post_id, e.table_code, comment_id,
       MIN(seen) as seen, MAX(date_time) as d_t,
       (CASE WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= CURDATE() THEN 'today'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 'yesterday'
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 'in last week'
            ELSE 'in last month'
        END) as range_day
FROM `events` e
WHERE e.id IN ($ids)
GROUP BY type, post_id, e.table_code, comment_id, range_day
ORDER BY seen, MAX(date_time) desc, MAX(e.id) desc;
```

More comments:

- The `IN ($ids)` probably doesn't do what you expect.  The variables `$ids` is treated as a single value, so this is equivalent to `e.di = $ids`.
- If this doesn't do what you want, then you might want `MAX()` at some other level of aggregation.  That would require an additional subquery.

Comment: *"Max of what?"* I want MAX of `date_time` when several rows are added together. I mean when `SUM()` aggregates some rows, then I need to use the biggest `date_time` of those rows.

Comment: Odd .. your query works as expected .. But I'm sure it shouldn't !!! I really don't know how it works.

Comment: @stack the problem is that in your existing query which rows the max should be pulled from is unclear. Normally it would be the max from the values among the rows in each set of grouping values; but your grouping includes the max expression indirectly, so you are asking for max for each max value which implies two stages of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

First, your problem...

You cannot `GROUP BY` an aggregate.  Notice the `MAX()` inside `range_day`.  Your `GROUP BY` *should* include all non-aggregate items in the `SELECT`.  `context` is missing and *may* lead to an error in subsequent releases.

Then another problem...

```
         MIN(seen) seen,
         MAX(d_t) d_t,
...
ORDER BY seen,
         MAX(d_t) desc
```

Notice an inconsistency?  An ambiguity?  Is `seen` (in the `ORDER BY`) supposed to be the original `seen`, or the alias `seen`, meaning `MIN(seen)`?  Ditto for `d_t`?

Always try to avoid having an alias spelled the same as a column name when you need to refer to it later.  In `WHERE`, it must be the column name; in `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`, it is the alias.

So, *I think*, this is wrong:  `MAX(d_t) desc` in the `ORDER BY`.